# AWS instance times out randomly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting, instance, minecraft

So recently I have set up my own EC2 free tier instance to host a simple Minecraft server. I have assigned the instance an elastic ip, gave it the ability to allow all traffic through port 25566 and port 22. 
At first, I thought it was every 12 hours that the instance would time out but the time frame seems to be getting worse. Every 6 or so hours the server will time out and I will have to restart the instance (stop and start) to be able to ssh back into the server and restart the Minecraft server.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Am I missing something?

Comment: What is in the log files?  Both the operating system and Minecraft should have some logs.  At a guess you're running out of memory but without logs there is no way to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few possibilities for this issue:

1. Your CPU credits are running out and you hosted on low capacity box
2. Someone (bot/hacker) hitting your box heavily to keep CPU busy (could happen if you opened port to whole world).
   Opening port 22 to whole world is not a good practice. Here is an issue discussed in [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=77194)
3. You have memory leak in your application

Look at your CPU usage by login to "CloudWatch" and monitor your cpu credit balance etc., If you see these are high, then you might need to upgrade the box.